# Yelp API - Getting JSON Results

Tags: php, jquery, json, oauth, yelp

I'm new to JSON and Yelp's API. I'm trying to search the API with a form. Here's my HTML:

```
<div>
    <form action="sample.php" method="post">
    <label>Term</label>&nbsp;<input name="term" id="term" type="text"/>
    <label>Location</label>&nbsp;<input name="location" id="location" type="text"/>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submitRest" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>

    <div id="success"></div>

    <div id="result">Result</div>
</div>
```

I'm submitting the form via ajax here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax(url, {
            data : formData,
            type : "POST",
            success : function(response){
                $('#success').html("<p>It worked!</p><p>" + <?php $getYelpData ?> + "</p>")
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem lies in "sample.php". It consists of this Oauth call:

```
require_once('lib/OAuth.php');

    $Term = (isset($_POST['term'])) ? $_POST['term'] : '';
    $Location = (isset($_POST['location'])) ? $_POST['location'] : '';

    function getYelpData($Term, $Location) {
        $URL = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=" . $Term . "&amp;location=" . $Location; 

        $CONSUMER_KEY = -;
        $CONSUMER_SECRET = -;
        $TOKEN = -;
        $TOKEN_SECRET = -;

        $AuthToken = new OAuthToken($TOKEN, $TOKEN_SECRET);
        $Consumer = new OAuthConsumer($CONSUMER_KEY, $CONSUMER_SECRET);

        $AuthRequest = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token(
            $Consumer, 
            $AuthToken, 
            'GET', 
            $URL
        );

        $AuthRequest->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $Consumer, $AuthToken);

        $Handle = curl_init($AuthRequest->to_url());
        curl_setopt($Handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($Handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $YelpResponse = curl_exec($Handle); // Yelp response
        curl_close($Handle);

        return json_decode($YelpResponse,true);
    }
```

How do I grab the JSON data from $YelpResponse? The ajax displays the success message, so I know it's working, but I'm not sure how to get the data I want out of it.

Comment: Where do you want to work with the data...in javascript on the client side, or in php on the server side. If on the server, simply do `$resp = json_decode($YelpResponse);` then `foreach($resp as $idx => $obj){//iteration }` if in ajax, return the object `return $YelpResponse` add `dataType:'json'` to your `ajax` call, and then iterate it with `$.each(response, function(i,obj){ console.log(obj) });`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I seem to be having a lot of trouble grasping where I'm going wrong. To answer your question I don't know. I'm assuming I just want the data on the client side. I only want the results displayed in a list.